# Contextmenu on listview datatemplate not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple ListView bound to a collection of Calculations. The view calls the calc Name property in the display. I have set the contextmenu to the individual items in the listview but on right click the context menu shows up as a tiny box with nothing in. What am i missing?

```
    <ListView x:Name="CalcList" ItemsSource="{Binding Calculations}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type lib:Calculation">
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="CalcMenu">
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete Calculation" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Another"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Another"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                    <Border.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ContextMenu="{StaticResource CalcMenu}"/>
                    </Border.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock MouseLeftButtonDown="DisplayCalc" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>                       
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, you have a syntax error the way you define the Border.ContextMenu element. The correct syntax (of the Border Element):

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
        Margin="2"
        ContextMenu="{StaticResource CalcMenu}">
     <TextBlock ... />
</Border>
```

Saying that, there is a lot of optimization you can do. First, instead of instantiating a context menu for each item, you can move the CalcMenu to the  section (one level up), or even farther up - to the main window.

Second, why do you define a separate context menu for each item? Is it really important context menu won't popu when mouse is in the margin between items? simply set the context menu to the entire list:

```
<ListView x:Name="CalcList" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CalcMenu}">
    ...
```

and define the CalcMenu as a main window resources, or inline the ListView element (not a static resource).

Comment: Thanks Uri. I had moved the resource down just to have a look at it but not realised the syntax error.